# How to chain these methods together (Geocoder + Pagination)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, rails-geocoder

I currently have an array of locations using the geocoder gem:

`@locations = Location.near([@lat, @lon], 3)`

which produces:

```
=> [#<Location id: 18, address: "555 N 7th Ave, Jamaica, CA  66666", phone: "(623) 555-5555", latitude: 66.666, longitude: -200.082, user_id:  1, created_at: "2015-03-11 15:06:57", updated_at: "2015-03-11 15:06:57">,

#<Location id: 46, address: "555 N 7th Ave, Jamaica, CA  66666", phone: "(623) 555-5555", latitude: 66.666, longitude: -200.082, user_id: 1, created_at: "2015-03-11 15:06:57", updated_at: "2015-03-11 15:06:57">]
```

I'm trying to add pagination to these results with

```
@locations = Location.near([@lat, @lon], 3).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
```

and in the view (haml):

```
= will_paginate @locations
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*, 3958.755864232 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((33.457341299999996 - locations.lati' at line 1: SELECT COUNT(locations.*, 3958.755864232 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((33.457341299999996 - locations.latitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS(33.457341299999996 * PI() / 180) * COS(locations.latitude * PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN((-112.07359500000001 - locations.longitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2))) AS distance, MOD(CAST((ATAN2( ((locations.longitude - -112.07359500000001) / 57.2957795), ((locations.latitude - 33.457341299999996) / 57.2957795)) * 57.2957795) + 360 AS decimal), 360) AS bearing) FROM `locations`  WHERE (locations.latitude BETWEEN 33.41392176506674 AND 33.50076083493325 AND locations.longitude BETWEEN -112.12563828858949 AND -112.02155171141054 AND (3958.755864232 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((33.457341299999996 - locations.latitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS(33.457341299999996 * PI() / 180) * COS(locations.latitude * PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN((-112.07359500000001 - locations.longitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2)))) BETWEEN 0.0 AND 3)):
```

Any idea?

Comment: I also see now that pagination doesn't naturally work with ordinary arrays (but pagination collections), still don't understand the sql error.

Comment: The same code works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried rendering @locations separately in your template?  This is the pattern I typically use:

```
= will_paginate
render @locations
= will_paginate
```

This should at least help you isolate the problem.